# How to display the French character ’?

Tags: french

I am using charset Cp037 and able to display all the French chars for example :  été  à
But not able to display only ’ ( tilted apostrophe) please let me know the charset to be used.

I have tried ISO-8859-1 and didn't work.

Comment: You mean the character 0xB4? See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1#Code_page_layout, it is in ISO-8859-1

Comment: @Progman thanks for your comment! what my code looks like is :  Response.ContentType= "application/json; charset=Cp037"   this displays all the French chars except ’   
Example Output: "LAWB a été mise à jour par un autre agent.Vous devez récupérer linformation à jour avant de poursuivre."   
here after L and between AWB there is char ’  which is not displayed. 

thanks in advance.

Comment: Cp037 does have the character as well, see http://www.kreativekorp.com/charset/encoding/CP037/. Check the byte sequence of the data, if the 0xB4 byte is at the expected location or not. Then [edit] your question to include the byte sequence of the message you want to display. If the byte 0xB4 is not in the byte sequence of the message, then there is nothing to display.